# Custom iPad theme not showing up correctly

Tags: ipad, ios, jailbreak

I created a theme for iPad and am having a couple problems with it. In my theme are two custom icons, a wallpaper, and two png files for dock (one for landscape and one for portrait). The file structure for the theme is as follows:

---

**CustomTheme.theme**

- Bundles

  - com.apple.springboard

    - SBDockBGT-Landscape.png
    - SBDockBGT-Portrait.png
- Icons

  - Coverflow.png
  - MediaVideo.png
- Info.plist
- Wallpaper.png

---

1.) The two icons were created as the same size in Photoshop, but when I SSH the theme to the iPad, one is displayed bigger than the other.

2.) The other problem is my theme wallpaper is zoomed incorrectly and does not change orientation. It displays correctly when I use the `Set As Wallpaper` option from iOS though. I just want to know how do do it in a theme...

Any suggestions?

Thanks!
Thomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Switching off SummerBoard Mode](http://www.ipodtouchfans.com/forums/showthread.php?t=293684) fixed the icon issue.